# Create a Custom Android Menu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-menu

I'm trying to build a custom menu screen for my Android app through using a `RecyclerView`. However, when I try to create a `MenuItem` for my ArrayList, the app crashes when I try to open `activity_menu.xml` screen. How would I make it to where the `options_menu.xml` populate the `activity_menu.xml RecyclerView`? Thank you!

**My end result**

[image]

**What I have**

[image]

**activity_menu.xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/menuRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />
```

**MenuActivity.kt**

```
class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var menuAdapter: MenuAdapter
    val menuList = ArrayList<MenuItem>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)

        createMenu()
    }

    private fun createMenu() {

        menuAdapter = MenuAdapter(this, menuList)

        val menuRecycleView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.menuRecyclerView)
        menuRecycleView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MenuActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            adapter = menuAdapter
            setHasFixedSize(true)
        }

    }

}
```

**options_meny.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:icon="@drawable/outline_person_"
        android:title="@string/my_profile" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:icon="@drawable/bookings_"
        android:title="@string/my_bookings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:icon="@drawable/payment_"
        android:title="@string/payment" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu4"
        android:icon="@drawable/on_going_jobs_"
        android:title="@string/on_going_jobst" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu5"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings_"
        android:title="@string/settings" />
    
</menu>
```

**item_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/iconImageButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_photo_"
            android:contentDescription="@string/string_menu_icon_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menuLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_label"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconImageButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuArrowImageView"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/right_chevron_"
            android:contentDescription="@string/menu_arrow" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**MenuItem.kt**

```
class MenuItem constructor(val menuName: String = "", val menuImage: String = "")
```

**MenuAdapter.kt**

```
class MenuAdapter(var context: Context, var list: ArrayList<MenuItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder?.bindItems(list[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        fun bindItems(items: MenuItem) {
            val menuName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.menuLabelTextView)
            val menuImage = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iconImageView)

            menuName.text = items.menuName
            Picasso.get().load(items.menuImage).into(menuImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't need `options_menu`. 2. Your. `menuList` is an empty array. 3. Add `MenuItem` with relevant parameter values to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you haven't added any item to your list yet, and based on that the recycler view doesn't show anything because the item count of it's adapter is zero